# How to speed up nested loop through DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I wrote a script in which I want to compare 2 AMIs (kind of ID of the AWS instance) in Pandas DataFrame. I am importing data from csv file which contains almost 9000 rows.  In the column "Product" I have name of the system which is running on this (it can be Linux/UNIX, Red Hat Enterprise Linux or Windows). I am comparing these AMIs one from Linux and other one from Red Hat with two nested loops and if they are the same in the new column "System" assign to both them name "Linux/UNIX". The only thing which I improved in this script is the first loop (i range) is going only through Linux/UNIX instances and j range is running through Red Hat ones because before running it I sorted DataFrame by "Product" column and now i range is around 5600 rows and j range around 1600 instead of 9000x9000. It has improved execution time significantly. However, it is still too slow. Is there any chance to speed it up even more? Thanks in advance!

dfs is my sorted DataFrame.

```py
dfs=df.sort_values("Product",axis=0,ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True).copy()

for i in range(0,len(dfs)-list(dfs["Product"])[::-1].index("Linux/UNIX")):
    for j in range(list(dfs["Product"]).index("Red Hat Enterprise Linux"),len(dfs)-list(dfs["Product"])[::-1].index("Red Hat Enterprise Linux")):
        if dfs['AMI'][i]==dfs['AMI'][j]:
            dfs['System'][i]="Linux/UNIX"
            dfs['System'][j]="Linux/UNIX"
        else:
            dfs['System'][i]="Linux/UNIX"
            dfs['System'][j]="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
```

I want to have something like that:
[image]

When the AMI is the same on different products(Linux and Red Hat) it should put in column "System" Linux/UNIX

Comment: Can you create a small example of your data with desired output. Please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: We normally try to avoid manual iteration when using pandas DataFrames. Have you looked at any alternatives in pandas?

Comment: What alternative could i use here to iterate through this column?

Comment: Please add an small example input dataframe and it's expected output to the question. Currently it's hard to understand what you actually want.

Comment: The input data frame is totally the same just it is not sorted by column "Product". I mean the code is correct it is assigning well System in the output dataframe. I have only problem with optimization. I would like to know how can i change these nested loops for something else more time efficient?

Comment: I used method iterrows instead of range but it the execution time is comparable to this before. Is it possible to somehow do it with apply?